# How do I overwrite old img uploads with new img uploads if they have different extensions

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a profile image upload system.  The user is allowed to upload any type image file extension type they want.  When the user uploads a jpeg, and then a png, both images are stored inside the uploads folder I made.  I want to overwrite the old profile image and only use their latest upload.  My code is kind of specific and I've been having trouble finding similar solutions online.  Does anyone know what I should do?  Thank you.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
                    $id = $_SESSION['userID'];
                    $userid = "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username='$id'";
                    $pictureExist = "SELECT status FROM profileimg WHERE userid='$userid'";
                    if ($pictureExist == 0) {
                        echo "<div class='userPicture'><img src='uploads/profile".$id.".jpg?'".mt_rand()."></div>";
                            } 
                    else {
                        echo "<div class='userPicture'><img src='uploads/noUser.png'></div>";
                    }
```

The Line in question is the profile img source line

I need .jpg? to be something like $fileActualExt but that didnt work when I tried it. :(

Comment: How is the data stored in your db? where do you store the path to the image link? to you have an ext field in the db? These would help.

Comment: basically you should not just be storing the image in an uploads folder, you should have a table that maps images data. So table profileimg should also have a filed path_to_file, ext, name, date_uploaded and things of the sort.

This way you would just fetch it with the sql query and inject that into the `src` prop.

Comment: My database is literally just a folder on my desktop atm, im working on getting it set up and working before I do anything official.  You mentioned a table?  Which program should i use for that?

Comment: Presumably you are using a database since you are using select statements, so create a table in the database you are using and save the file name/path into a row. That way if someone were to update with a new uploaded file, you can save the file to the directory, remove the original file from the directory, then update the new path/file name in the table for that file id.

Comment: @AdamJones You are using SELECT statements which are for SQL db so something somewhere in your app is probably functioning with it. Look into mySQL and XAMPP / LAMMP for further tools to work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($pictureExist == 0) {
                    $filename = "uploads/profile".$id."*";
                    $fileinfo = glob($filename);
                    $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
                    $fileactualext = $fileext[1];
                    echo "<div class=userPicture><img src='uploads/profile".$id.".".$fileactualext."?".mt_rand()."'></div>";
                }
```